# Book where main character is an alien but doesn’t know

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’m trying to find a book (teen SciFI I guess) I read probably in 1998ish. There was a girl living on a alien planet. Someone looked after her but not a parent. I think she had to wear a suit all the time. She had a pet dog type thing which dies (it gets attacked by another alien animal). She finds out she is a scarlet alien creature and she didn’t know! Any ideas? I think there is a human boy there who she makes friends with. She thinks she is a human and that she has to wear the suit to breathe but it is to hide her true identity.

Comment: Hi! [See our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to improve your question.

Comment: This sounds like it's probably Monica Hughes' *The Keeper of the Isis Light.*

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/ya-series-with-a-housekeeper-or-protector-robot-and-set-on-a-planet-with-a-harsh Does this fit your recollection?

Comment: Yes that’s it! Thank you soooo much!